# Query to multiple csv fles at S3 through Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I exported my SQL DB into S3 in csv format. Each table is exported into separate csv files and saved in Amazon S3. Now, can I send any query to that S3 bucket which can join multiple tables (multiple csv files in S3) and get a result-set? How can I do that and save in a separate csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are:

- Put all files related to one table into a *separate* folder (directory path) in the S3 bucket. Do not mix files from multiple tables in the same folder because Amazon Athena will assume they all belong to one table.
- Use the [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) to define a new table in Amazon Athena, and specify where the files are kept via the `LOCATION 's3://bucket_name/[folder]/'` parameter. This tells Athena which folder to use when reading the data.

Or, instead of using `CREATE TABLE`, an easier way is:

- Go to the **AWS Glue management console**
- Select **Create crawler**
- Select **Add a data source** provide the location in S3 where the data is stored
- Provide other information as prompted (you'll figure it out)

Then, **run the crawler** and AWS Glue will look at the data files in the specified folder and will automatically create a table for that data. The table will appear in the Amazon Athena console.

Once you have created the tables, you can use normal SQL to query and join the tables.

Comment: Now, folder in S3 name is "csv"

As advised, created 25 folders under "csv" and saved csv files for tables in separate folders

Crawler seems to be ok

Applied following SQL

SELECT * FROM "s3_file_list"."calender_dimension_hourly" limit 10;

That is giving following error:

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed from relation that has no columns
This query ran against the "s3_file_list" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id: f1f443ee-ffdc-4c67-8bc6-28457514b343

Please help

Comment: I don't know what you setup, but basically you should create a table (or run the crawler to create a table) **for each folder separately**. So, if you have 25 CSV files that represent 25 different tables, then you will need 25 sub-folders and a CSV file in each folder. Then, use `CREATE TABLE` 25 times, each with a different location OR use the Glue Crawler 25 times to define each table separately.

Comment: I followed exactly what you advised and that worked like a charm. 

I figured out what issue happened. Out of 25 tables some tables were empty. That following error was coming for empty tables. However the alert is little misleading :-)

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed from relation that has no columns This query ran against the "s3_file_list" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: f1f443ee-ffdc-4c67-8bc6-28457514b343

Thanks a lot for your advise. That is working like butter now :-)

Comment: Great! You can use **Generate Table DDL** in Amazon Athena (click the 3 dots next to a table) to see the syntax that was used to create the table. You can then modify it to create other tables in future. I like using AWS Glue to write the first version, then I can modify it by hand for other tables.